# рекурсия в задаче

Tags: рекурсия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задача состоит в том чтобы вложенный массив сконвертировать в обычный. у меня вопрос. 
почему после условия идет сразу рекурсия? она сначала делает итерацию по листу и ставит условие является ли i листом. только это.  что вообще делает reemovNestings(i)?
код рабочий.

Comment: Условие проверяет, является ли очередной элемент списком (вложенным). Если является, то вызываем функцию для этого вложенного списка. Если не является списком, то очередной элемент добавляется в "обычный" список. Советую выполнить этот код на бумаге, чтобы понять.

Comment: Ну неужели было трудно скопировать код в вопрос текстом? тут, небось, не инстаграмм...